# The matching mechanism of the server block of nginx

Tags: nginx

A cloud server, public ip is `8.130.104.xxx`, internal ip is `172.16.38.191`, nginx is deployed on it, and the server configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen      8.130.104.xxx:80;
    server_name example.org;

    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"server_name":"$server_name", "host": "$host", "server_addr":"$server_addr"}';
}

server {
    listen      172.16.38.191:80;
    server_name example.org;

    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"server_name":"$server_name", "host": "$host", "server_addr":"$server_addr"}';
 
}
```

When I use `curl 172.16.38.191`, accessing the intranet address, it returns:

```json
{"server_name":"example.org", "host": "172.16.38.191", "server_addr":"172.16.38.191"}
```

It matches the server block of '172.16.38.191', which is correct.

When I use `curl 8.130.104.xxx`, accessing the public address, it returns:

```json
{"server_name":"example.org", "host": "8.130.104.xxx", "server_addr":"172.16.38.191"}
```

It still matches the server block of '172.16.38.191'.

Why does nginx access the server block of the public network address that matches the internal network address? Is there any special mechanism inside?

Comment: Perhaps your network packets (generated by CURL) are coming to the server through the internal network interface rather than through the external network interface and are simply forwarded between the 2 interfaces. Try adding `bind` flag to each `listen` directive and make sure CURL calls are made on the proper side of the network.

Comment: I tried using a PC located on another network, using a browser, and browsing to the public address `8.130.104.xxx`, but nginx still matches the server block of `172.16.38.191`,  which is the internal network.

Comment: Can you try opening the page on your phone, using 4G and not WiFi - just to confirm that the packets are actually going to the public interface ? Try this after adding the `bind` flag to each `listen` directive.